# Blender Internal Render Material/Texture Mapping Issue: Texture standing out far more than normal on a different object

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I'm having a problem with something that I do not really know about, or how it began, or what it even is. In my file, I had several base objects, and then I created another one, assigned the same modifiers to such, and applied the same material to it. This was the result:
[image]

The two objects have the exact same material, yet the marble texture seems to stand out far more than the other to the point where I can't use the material on the arm to achieve a desired effect. When I tried duplicating and separating the original object, I found it did the same once I made it it's own object, separate from the original. I have no idea why this is, I tried different varying things of use, such as copy/pasting the material, altering the marble texture, and some other things, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

(Btw, the marble texture is mapped through Generated Flat.)

Here is the .blend file, it is not the entire original file, because I did not want to share the entirety of the file publicly yet.

[image]

Comment: can you upload your .blend? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ remember to pack external data into file before saving.

Comment: It's uploaded to the post

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have the "Geometry box ticked?  That's under the texture properties, right down the bottom under "Influence".

Comment: Yeah, I have the normal set to 0.18. Nothing else is checked in the geometry tab.

Comment: Actually it's suppose to be Generated:Sphere.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or_-Edur46I

Comment: You're doing good at modeling Bonnie V3 Zac

Comment: I actually have that whole model done, I can give it to you if you so want it, but it's like 300,000 vertices and some parts of the texture I couldn't figure out, (Like the cracks)